# number of generator needed for smaller ideal is less than the bigger ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, $\frak{a} \subset \frak{b}$ be two different ideal in $A$, assume that $\frak{b}$ is generated by $r$ elements. Can I deduce that number of generators for $\frak{a}$ is always less than or equals to $r$?

---

I tried to find a subset of generators for $\frak{b}$ that generates $\frak{a}$ however the elements in this set used to generate $\frak{a}$ may not lies in $\frak{a}$, so it can not be the generator of $\frak{a}$. So it's not very clear for me, maybe there are some counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an obvious family of counterexamples.

Take your favourite **non principal** Noetherian domain $A$. Pick any non principal ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ and set $\mathfrak{b}=A$. Then $\mathfrak{b}$ is generated by one element (that is $1$) but $\mathfrak{a}$ is generated by at least two elements since it is not principal.

Comment: Oh thank you GreginGre, I can take $ A = k[x,y]$ with ${\frak{a}} = (x,y)$